# Adobe Lightroom - get images from preview cache?

Tags: cache, adobe-lightroom

Is it possible to extract images from Lightroom's preview cache? For example if I lose some of the original image files before weekly backup.

JPEG Preview is set to Medium size so I would not get the full images but it'd be better than nothing.

I'm using version 2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lightroom stores its previews as `lrpreview` files. I've heard you can extract them using [BitmapRip](http://mark0.net/soft-bitmaprip-e.html), but a better approach would be using this [Lightroom Extract Cached Images Plugin](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/preview-extraction).

(I just saw that this question has already been answered over at [photo.stackexchange.com](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7166/how-to-extract-thumbnail-photos-from-lightroom-2-catalog), see there for more details.)

Comment: Nice, the Lightroom Extract Cached Images Plugin seems to be exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I'm glad I could help!